# How to fix angular app reloading on normal hyperlink when it is inserted via innerHtml property?

Tags: angular, hyperlink, innerhtml

I've got an alert component which has a `message` property. The message may be some text with a hyperlink in it:

`An error occured. <a href="/learn-more">Learn more</>`

The `message` is inserted via `innerHtml`:

`<div class="alert-text" [innerHtml]="alert.message"></div>`

When I click the link, it reloads the app. What can I do to fix this?

Angular: *7.1.0*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

innerHTML does not bind any angular event that's why it's not working
to make it work you need to create custom directive which is responsible for route navigation.

**check the working sample** - https://stackblitz.com/edit/skdroid-innerhtml-routing

custom directive - CustomRouteDirective

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCustomRoute]'
})
export class CustomRouteDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private router: Router) { }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  public onClick(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName === 'A') {
      this.router.navigate([event.target.getAttribute('href')]);
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
```

html code - `<div appCustomRoute [innerHTML]="sampleHTML"></div>`