# Add Angular html code in non-declarative way

Tags: angular

We are using a third party component to set a list of remarks in Angular.
The remarks are set in typescript as an array. The component supports putting html.
We would like to put a piece of html on the remark to navigate to another angular route in the same application.
How can we dynamically add angular-enabled html in Typescript in a non-declarative way.

So we need something like this:

```
this.remarks = [
    { content: 'go to <a routerLink="somewhere-in-current-app">this link</a>
];
```

Comment: you just want to put HTML inside remarks.content to the component HTML Right? if so did you used [innerHtml] directive.

Comment: yes the component uses innerHtml. But we don't control is so we would like to keep it that way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix angular app reloading on normal hyperlink when it is inserted via innerHtml property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55941217/how-to-fix-angular-app-reloading-on-normal-hyperlink-when-it-is-inserted-via-inn)

Comment: It is not a duplicate

Comment: Angular replaces Angular specific markup at build time with a generated code. Markup added at runtime won't be processed by Angular, so you have to use the custom directive to parse HTML, for now, this is the only option.